# How to skip match data when select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database-

First Table Named area:

```
id name
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

Second Table Named data:

```
id name area_id end_date
1   a1   1,2     2014-07-14 09:50:00
```

I want to select rows from first table only if that **id** is not present in **area_id** set of my second table and whose **end_date** is greater than or equal to current date.

my query (not working) -

```
select a.* from area as a  where a.id NOT IN (
            SELECT find_in_Set(area_id) FROM data
                WHERE date(end_date)>=CURRENT_DATE()
        )
```

Comment: Can you change your table structure? Storing multiple values in a single column is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question right and the result of this query should be

```
id | name
---------
 3 | c
```

then you could get your result with a little modification. You forgot the needle that should be found in the set:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM area as a  
WHERE a.id NOT IN (
    SELECT FIND_IN_SET(a.id, area_id) FROM data    -- you forgot the needle
            WHERE date(end_date) >= CURRENT_DATE()
)
```

But I would recommend to follow the good advice of juergen d and change the table structure, if you can.